# MongoDB Robomongo: db.data.find(...).collation is not a function

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I'm trying to run:

`db.data.find({email: 'random@test.com'}).collation({locale:'en'})`

But I keep getting a .collation is not a function. Am I using the script wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Whats the version of your mongodb? It its 2.6, collation is not present. Try running db.version() in your mongo shell to check its version.

Comment: [collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/#collation-document-fields) in mongoDB 3.4 version

Comment: Collation is a new feature in MongoDB 3.4; Robomongo (as at 1.0) does not have support for MongoDB 3.4 yet. For updates see: https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/1250.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Collation' is introduced in MongoDB 3.4. It is now possible to use Mongo DB 3.4 with the latest beta: [Robomongo 1.1 - Beta version with MongoDB 3.4 Support](https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/1250#issuecomment-301036770). Fyi.